# How to implement a queue delay with Redis :: throttle when sending mail in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I do the newsletter for the site. And I want to limit of sent letters (queues)  per minute. For the limit I decided to use queues and redis::throttle. But when i run php artisan queue:work --tries=2 some emails in the logs are missing...

```
// Console command
$mailingList = MailingList::find(1);
dispatch(new SendDailyNewsletter($mailingList));

//App\Jobs\SendDailyNewsletter.php
class SendDailyNewsletter implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    //...

    public function handle()
    {
        $subscriptions = DB::table('mail as m')->select(['m.email'])->where('m.id', $this->mailing_list->id)->get();

        $subscriptions->each(function ($subscription) {
            logger($subscription->email);
        });

        $subscriptions->each(function ($subscription) {
            logger('+');
            Redis::throttle('key')->allow(1)->every(5)->then(function () use ($subscription) {
                logger($subscription->email);
            }, function () {
                return $this->release(5);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// foreach here all emails good
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: korwru@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: test@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: jackson33@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: hollie.emmerich@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: nbrakus@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: estrella.christiansen@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: elinor.frami@example.com  

//Redis::throttle some emails missed. Why?
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: +  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: korwru@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:30] local.DEBUG: +  
[2019-06-05 13:24:33] local.DEBUG: +  
[2019-06-05 13:24:35] local.DEBUG: jackson33@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:35] local.DEBUG: +  
[2019-06-05 13:24:38] local.DEBUG: +  
[2019-06-05 13:24:40] local.DEBUG: nbrakus@example.com  
[2019-06-05 13:24:40] local.DEBUG: +  
[2019-06-05 13:24:43] local.DEBUG: +
```

Tell me why the script skips some data(email)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to send one email every 5 seconds. One simple solution for this problem is the `sleep` command:

```
$subscriptions->each(function ($subscription) {
    // send email to:
    logger($subscription->email);
    sleep(5);
});
```

This solution has some **major downsides**: you have a very long running job blocking your queue. Additionally if this fails, retrying this job may lead to resending some of the emails.

What you want instead is a Job for every subscriber:

```
// SendDailyNewsletter
public function handle()
{
    $subscriptions = DB::table()..;

    // for every recipient of your newsletter create a new job
    $subscriptions->each(function ($subscription) {            
        SendDailyNewsletterToSubscriber::dispatch($subscription->email);
    });
}
```

Now we can use Redis::throttle to only send out one email every 5 seconds:

```
// handle function of SendDailyNewsletterToSubscriber
public function handle()
{
    Redis::throttle('key')->allow(1)->every(5)->then(function () {
        // send email to subscriber
        logger($this->email);
    }, function () {
        // could not obtain lock, retry this job in 5 seconds.
        return $this->release(5);
    });
}
```

---

Let me explain what happened in your script: in the first try of the `each()` loop Redis tries to obtain a lock on `key` and can acquire it. In the second iteration (test@example.com) Redis tries again to acquire the lock, but after 3 seconds it gives up (is skipping the email). In the third iteration it can obtain the lock after 2 seconds...

You can increase the waiting time for the lock by using `block()`. But this solution would be essentially the same as using the `sleep()` command with all downsides.

```
$subscriptions->each(function ($subscription) {
    logger('+');
    Redis::throttle('key')->allow(1)->every(5)->block(5)->then(function () use ($subscription) {
        logger($subscription->email);
    }, function () {
        return $this->release(5);
    });
});
```